# Can I configure Angular UI Bootstrap to use HTML valid attribute names?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In my project I use `uibTypeahead` directive from [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). Though I use this directive in `data-`-normalized form `<input data-uib-typeahead="..." />` which is valid HTML, the directive itself generate some HTML which uses invalid (according to HTML validation) attribute names e.g. `ng-class` and `ng-show`.

I'm now trying to make the whole code of my application pass [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to catch some problems that might have got overlooked, but I find it impossible to do, because of the severity of errors generated by invalid attribute names in markup generated by Angular UI Bootstrap `uibTypehead` directive.

Is there some way to configure Angular UI Bootstrap to normalize all the attributes in it's generated markup to use prefixed `data-` (or `x-`) form?

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate the `uibTypeahead` directive with your how html **normlized** names

put this on

```
angular.module('yourModule')
.config(['$provide'], functiond($provide){
$provide.decorator('uibTypeaheadPopupDirective', function($delegate) {
            directive = $delegate[0];
            directive.templateUrl = 'path_for/typeAheadPopup.html';

            return $delegate;
        });
$provide.decorator('uibTypeaheadMatchDirective', function($delegate) {
            directive = $delegate[0];
            directive.templateUrl = 'path_for/typeAheadMatch.html';

            return $delegate;
        });
```

and create your owns htmls files with your normlize names.

**typeAheadMatch.html Example**

```
<a href
tabindex="-1" data-ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"
data-ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}"></a>
```

You can have the example html from the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js on the templateCache.

```
angular.module("uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("uib/template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html",
```